# How do I determine where a process is being started from, and disable it?

Tags: launchd, macos, postgresql

When I start OS X (Mavericks) and run `ps aux | grep postgres` from Terminal, I have a process that was automatically started:

```
postgres          132   0.0  0.1  2526456   7936   ??  Ss   10:04PM   0:00.07 /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin/postmaster -D/Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/data
```

This is a problem because I recently installed HomeBrew's version of Postgres and want that to be the postgres that is always running.  However, I can't figure out how to disable the old one (above) and it is driving me crazy! I've looked for launch agents in:

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents
/Library/LaunchAgents
/Library/LaunchDaemons
/Library/StartupItems
/System/Library/LaunchAgents
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons
```

and can't seem to find one matching the above... any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, found it in /Library/LaunchDaemons on a careful second look... those really seem to be all the possible places that startup processes load from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The related [launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) job ticket was found in `/Library/LaunchDaemons`.

Answering to mark question as successfully resolved.